# How to avoid making EDT sleep when calling a method that has Thread.sleep

Tags: swing, thread-safety, jlabel, thread-sleep

So, I'm trying to make a JLabel's text look like the text is typing out. My problem is I'm not sure how to make sure the EDT doesn't sleep and the GUI still updates  Here is the code.

startGameText() gets called from somewhere else in the program. (questions is a JLabel.)

```
    public void startGameText() throws InterruptedException {


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

    w.questions.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    w.questions.setFont(new Font("Helveltica", Font.BOLD, 30));

    typeOutQuestions("....");


    String awoken = "You have awoken in a strange place. ";
    typeOutQuestions(awoken);


    String remember = "You only remember a few things..";
    typeOutQuestions(remember);





        }
});



    }
```

this is the method I want it to call to update the label questions.

```
public void typeOutQuestions(String s) throws InterruptedException{

    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i ++){

        int p = 0;
        w.questions.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        w.questions.setText(s.substring(p, i));
        p--;
        Thread.sleep(100);

    }

}
```

How would I make it so that questions is still updated through the EDT, but the EDT does not sleep?

Comment: Please make the code you have posted an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for us to easily revise your code.

Comment: Please try [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcvfmc3osh9l7qf/TypingTextExample.java), this might be able to give you some idea, how to go about this thingy :-). If anything is unclear, ask for it anytime. I would be happy to help on that too. About to go to sleep when I caught your question, so made a quick code example, though if you want slight changes, let me know or try yourself :-)

Comment: @Garrett : True, though `javax.swing.Timer` is to be used for short task like these, though if the task you performing is a bit huge, then use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) tasks are performed on EDT by default/or some other Thread (here performing GUI related tasks on EDT, will become the programmers responsibility), for that purpose. For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)